# remove '' from a list in python

Tags: python, list, text

I've got following text: [sherlock.txt](http://www.spoj.com/content/pdawyndt:sherlock.txt)
And I want to create a list of every word in it (punctuations are part of the word and are therefore not seperated elements e.g.:'glad.').
what I did was following:

```
>>> def wordlist(text):
...    input= open(text,'r')
...    data= input.read()
...    input.close()
...    data=data.replace('\n',' ')
...    data=data.replace(chr(13),' ')
...    data=data.replace(chr(9),' ')
...    data=data.split(' ')
...    while '' in data:
...        data.remove('')
...    return data
```

The problem is it returns a list of words but it takes approx. 7 seconds to do so. Is there a faster method to do this?I know that the while loop is the problem here.

Comment: What should this strange while loop do?

Comment: if I remove the while loop then it returns following list: `['ADVENTURE', 'I.', 'A', 'SCANDAL', 'IN', 'BOHEMIA', '', 'I.', '', 'To',...]`
As you can see there are `''` in the list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Was this not doing it?  Calling `split` without arguments splits the string on all whitespace characters, eliminating those `''` that were giving you problems before they even get considered part of data.  Since you're going to the trouble of changing those other whitespace characters to `' '`, you might as well just get the same effect for free with built-in, default behavior.

```
def wordlist(text):
    with open(text, "r") as fp:
        data = fp.read().split()
    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could just split the string.

```
data.split()
```

Which will split on whitespace and return an array.

[Documentation for split.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following does what you're looking for:

```
words = list(itertools.chain(*map(str.split, open('sherlock.txt'))))
```

On my machine, this takes 16.5ms.

By removing the call to `list()`, this could be converted into a generator that would return words as it's reading them, instead of storing all words in memory.

The following is simpler and faster, but is less memory-efficient (this might matter for larger input files):

```
words = open('sherlock.txt').read().split()
```

This takes about 6.7ms.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `split()` function without any argument at all. You don't need to do any `replace`-ing first, because it splits on **any** whitespace.

```
def wordlist(text):
...    input= open(text,'r')
...    data= input.read().split()
...    input.close()
...    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

For argument's sake we'll assume you can't get the blank strings out of your input. Obviously if you can do that it's the preferred method. A list comprehension can remove them otherwise:

```
data = [word for word in data if word]
```

The `if` part is simplified because an empty string evaluates to `False`.